# Vbulletin plugin development tutorial

Tags: plugins, module, vbulletin

I searched for tutorials but i didn't found any useful tutorial. I want to create simple plugin which add "123" to header of every pages of forum.

I tried to go to admin panel -> create new plugin. But i don't know what hook i need to display "123" in header.

I will be very thankful for any help.

Comment: What version of vBulletin are you running?

Answer (score 11):

Assuming vBulletin 4 and above:

**Create a Product**

1. Logon to your AdminCP
2. Goto Plugins & Products -> Manage Products
3. Click Add/Import Product
4. On the following screen enter your product name etc in the Add New Product section (you can leave Product URL and Product Check URL blank)

**Add a Plugin to your Product**

1. Goto Plugins & Products -> Add New Plugin
2. Select your Product
3. To add something to the header on every page select the global_bootstrap_init_complete hook location
4. In PHP code enter the following:

   $template_hook['mycustommesage'] = 'hello world';

**Update your header template to include the plugin output**

1. In ACP goto Styles & Templates -> Style Manager
2. Select the style you want to edit and select edit templates
3. Open the header template
4. Whereever you want you plugin output to appear add:

   {vb:raw template_hook.mycustommesage}

Comment: I have tried this its working. But can you please let me know i create plugin for vbulletin. Like i want to show one select field when thread owner will start the thread. Only for one time if any buddy will comment or reply then this select field will not show.How i do that please let me know. i am totally new in vbulletin