# How i create a vbulletin custom plugin

Tags: plugins, vbulletin

I want to create a vBulletin custom plug-in but I am new in vBulletin i don't know about the vBulletin. I have tried to download the plug-ins but only commercial user will download the plug-in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vbulletin plugin development tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349340/vbulletin-plugin-development-tutorial)

Comment: Do you read this tutorial? : http://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html/creating_a_product

Comment: I have checked both links in both link there is static custom plugin development. I want to show a select field during new thread created by thread owner.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific tutorial that you can follow to create a specific product, however there is a good tutorial from vBulletin which gives you a good idea on how to [create a vBulletin 'product' that can be downloaded and installed by others](http://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html/creating_a_product).

But basically to create a product you need to learn some basics and you have to know, php, html, css, and have a understanding of how vBulletin works. Then take it and put it all together.

To get a good understanding, I would recommend modifying other people's add-ons to suit your needs. That's how I was able to get a good understanding of how vBulletin works and then all you have to do as you progress, is to ask the right questions.

The recommendations bellow are also supported by well know vBulletin coders.
[Source](http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=307730).

PHP, basic guide: [PHP 5 Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/)

HTML basic guide: [HTML Tutorial - (HTML5 Compliant)](http://www.w3schools.com/html/)

CSS basic guide: [CSS Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/)

vBulletin basic mod guide: [Creating a Product](http://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html/creating_a_product)