# Target the end head tag to insert style sheet before it

Tags: php, string, replace, insert, vbulletin

I'm trying to add some things into the head section of a page the problem is I use a cms (vBulletin) so I have to do it through a plugin.  The plugin hooks into the page at the very end (after the closing html) so if my plugin is

```
echo('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">');
```

It ends up at the very end like

```
</html><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

is there anyway I can target the `</head>` tag and insert the style sheet before it?

I have tried

```
$string = "</head>";
$string = str_replace("</head>", "<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></head>", $string);
```

But that had no effect.

Sorry if I'm not asking this correctly, but I hope someone understands what I mean.

Comment: Your plugin is the problem. Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349340/vbulletin-plugin-development-tutorial